# Sum a list with timedeltas in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm struggling with following problem:

How can I sum a list of timedeltas like:

```
[datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)]
```

which should result in **datetime.timedelta(0, 14400)**  => 4 hours

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this,

```
import datetime
print sum(time_list,datetime.timedelta())
```

Result:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 14400)
```

Comment: that did work, thx

Answer (score 9):

Pass `datetime.timedelta(0,0)` to `sum` as init value.

```
import datetime

arr = [datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)]

print(sum(arr, datetime.timedelta(0,0)))
```

Output:

```
4:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame([datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)])
    df[0].sum()
    Timedelta('0 days 04:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution: use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce),

```
import operator
import functools
import datetime

dts = [datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)]

result = functools.reduce(operator.add, dts)

print(result)
# 4:00:00
```